# How can I continue the loop when I give scanf() a non-digit as input?

Tags: c, scanf

I worked out the simple example. Here it will get the integer value from the user and display the value.
When I am giving a character input instead of an integer, I want to skip the process and again
ask the user for input.
For that, I wrote this below code, but when I give a character input it will continue the looping, but while continue it will not ask a input to user.  Please give a solution for that.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
    int n;
    while(1){
            if(scanf("%d",&n)==0){
                    printf("Error:Checkyour input\n");
                    continue;
            }
            printf("the  input =%d\n",n);
    }
 }
```

the output comes like:

```
  Error:Checkyour input
  Error:Checkyour input
  Error:Checkyour input
  Error:Checkyour input
  Error:Checkyour input
  Error:Checkyour input
```

Comment: `continue;` --> `scanf("%*[^\n]");continue;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because, the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press [a `\n`] is stored in the input buffer and continuously provides the *wrong* input to [next] `scanf()`.

make the following changes to your code.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int  main()                          //add the return type.

  {
    int n;
    while(1){
            if(scanf(" %d",&n)==0){
                    while (getchar() !='\n');   //eat up all the _invalid_ input present in input buffer till newline
                    printf("Error:Check your input\n");
                    continue;
            }
            printf("the  input =%d\n",n);
    }
    return 0;                      //add the return value.

 }
```

In regards to Mr. [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler)'s comment, please find below a more optimized version of the code, taking care of `EOF` also.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int  main()

  {
    int n;
    int retval = 0;
    while(1){
            retval = scanf(" %d",&n);

            if (retval ==1)
                     printf("the  input =%d\n",n);
            else if (retval == 0)
            {
                    while (getchar() !='\n');
                    printf("Error:Check your input\n");
                    continue;
            }
            else                          //includes EOF case
                break;

    }
    return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Note that if the user indicates EOF (typing control-D on a typical Unix machine), then you have an infinite loop (because `scanf()` doesn't return 0).  Also, if the user indicates EOF after typing a letter or punctuation, you get a different infinite loop (because `getchar()` doesn't return newline).  Always consider EOF too.

Comment: Right. Will update my answer accordingly. Thanks :-).

Comment: One of the two infinite loops I diagnosed is fixed.  I might use `while ((retval = scanf("%d", &n)) != EOF)` as the outer loop condition (I avoid infinite loops when I can).

Answer (score 1):

When `scanf()` fails to convert something (e.g. you typed a letter `a` instead of a digit), it leaves the character it cannot read in the input to be processed by another I/O call.  If that is the same `scanf()` again, it will fail again, ad nauseam.  Your code will also misbehave if it gets EOF on standard input.

You have various options to fix it:

1. You can break the loop when `scanf()` doesn't return 1, stopping on the first error or EOF.
2. You can use `getchar()` to read at least the character that stopped the input, optionally reading up to the next newline (or EOF).
3. You can use a different `scanf()` format to read the junk: `scanf("%*[-+0-9]")` for example, to skip over all characters that are not a part of an integer.  Note, however, that this could leave `--` in the input, so it isn't all that safe.  Maybe `scanf("%*[^ \n]")` would be better.  The `*` suppresses assignment, so it doesn't need somewhere to place the data that's read.